# Implementing Transactions in mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

Below are my queries

```
 $db= new mysqli('localhost','user','passcode','dbname');
try {
// First of all, let's begin a transaction
$db->beginTransaction();

// A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
$query1="insert into table1(id,name) values('1','Dan')";
$query2="insert into table2(id,name) values('2','Anaba')";

// If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
// i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
$db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
// An exception has been thrown
// We must rollback the transaction
$db->rollback();
}
```

Please I am trying to implement transaction in mysql queries through php, I would like to fail all queries when one of the queries fail. The above code throws an error("Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::beginTransaction()").Please is there any better solution or idea to solve the problem.Thanks for your help

Comment: This is unrelated to the transactions - but where are you actually running these queries? The code you've shown is just assigning them to strings.

Comment: I am running these queries in a browser through a php script.

Comment: I mean - the code you show doesn't actually execute the queries.

Comment: Yes please, it doesn't execute the queries but rather it shows the error message aforementioned.

Answer (score 10):

```
$db->begin_transaction();
```

not

```
$db->beginTransaction();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

If earlier than PHP 5.5, then use

```
$db->autocommit(true);
```

instead

Comment: It shouldn't be the **same** error, since the error message references `beginTransaction`, which should no longer be in your code. Please include the exact new error message.

Comment: Please this is the error it gives after updating it with begin_transaction(). " Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::begin_transaction() in /var/www/books.php on line 19"

Comment: Please sorry for the wrong information, I just confirmed from my server, It is rather PHP 5 version.Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Please after applying the $db->autocommit(true), it throws no error but the first query works while the second query fails.

Comment: Both the autocommit(false) and autocommit(right) give the same result.

Comment: Please show your actual code. mysqli will not throw exceptions for errors - you have to check for `false`, and throw an exception yourself in order to get to your `rollback` call.

Comment: Please which of the codes should I show? What will be the correct syntax to start transaction?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks buddy, you saved me. I just wanted to know if I need to use deadlock prevention in transactions like in this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php link.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, [`begin_transaction()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) is new in PHP 5.5. (just released a couple weeks ago)

If you're getting an error saying that it doesn't exist, it probably means you're using an older version of PHP.

If you think you are running PHP 5.5, please verify your PHP version by running this earlier in your same script:

```
echo(phpversion());
```

Sometimes there's multiple versions of PHP present on a machine, and your script may not actually be executing in the version that you think it is.

Comment: Please I am using PHP 5 version.

Comment: PHP 5 is not necessarily PHP 5.5. PHP 5.5 was just released a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Please I have corrected my earlier comment, I was sorry for the wrong information,I just verified from my server and it was PHP 5 not PHP 5.5.Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a $count, something like that:

```
$err_count = 0;
$query1 = "insert into table1(id,name) values('1','Dan')";
if(!$query1) 
    $err_count++;

if($err_count>0) 
    throw new Exception("error msg");
```

Comment: Please, it is not responding at all.Thanks